# Solving a 3 by 4 matrix with 4 variables

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

I had this question on my exam and I thought I could solve it using the row echelon method. Well, I couldn't, and I still don't know how to solve it. We were asked to "determine $a$ such the equation system has a unique solution" and to determine $a$ itself. The system had three equations:

$2x - y + az = 3$

$3x - 4y + 2az = 1$

$x + y - z = 2$.

Could you provide me with a step-by-step of how to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: have you considered cramers rule?

Comment: I heard that could work but I haven't studied that yet. Is it not doable with row-echelon?

Comment: I don't know about row-echelon, but if you just want to work out the problem, Cramer's rule will take 2 minutes to learn and is very easy to apply.

Comment: Yea i just learned Kramer's formula and it was pretty easy to get the results. Does Kramer's rule apply to any matrix?

Comment: Cramer's rule is only applicable when the system has unique solution, this is, same number of equations and unknowns. But as I remember, is very inefficient for systems larger than 3 equations and numerically unstable.

Answer (score 1):

After some row operations, your augmented matrix becomes

$$ \left[ \matrix{ 1 & -1/2 & a/2 \cr 0 & 1 & -a/5 \cr 0 & 0 & -1-a/5 \cr} \right| \left. \matrix{3/2\cr 7/5\cr -8/5}\right]$$

In order for this to have a solution, what you need is $-1-a/5 \ne 0$, i.e. $a \ne -5$.

Answer (score 1):

You could also demonstrate the value of $a$ that makes the system incompatible, this means that the system will have solution for any value distinct from that value of $a$.

This is proven taking the determinant of the coefficient matrix $A$ and looking for which value(s) of $a$ is zero.

$\det(A) = \begin{bmatrix} 2&-1&a \\ 3&-4&2a \\ 1&1&-1 \end{bmatrix} = 0 \Rightarrow 5+a=0 \Rightarrow a = -5$

When $a=-5$ the determinant is zero thus $A$'s rank is less than $A^*$ (augmented) rank, so the system has no solution as stated in [Rouché-Capelli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem).

For the rest of the problem, use Gauss-Jordan by putting the matrix in row echelon form, or use Cramer's Rule since it would be easy to calculate in this context.